# How to have master iPhone application to market sub apps?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, master-detail

I am having around 10 live iPhone mobile applications in my account under same category (All Tamil devotional), and going to add more. All applications have In App purchase.

I want to create a master application through which user able to buy all my smaller apps. Is it possible? If so, is there any sample application in store?

Comment: It is not possible, as far I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no any sample app, specific to like this on App store but you can do even better at your end.

If all your apps are of same categories, then  you could do a common app and implement categories according to the apps and upload it to the app store.

So user can download your common app only once and they'll get all your features, of course your in app purchase is distributed category wise in a common app.